# Is in Drupal the way to cache whole region?

Tags: caching, theming

I have a region which contain several blocks, each of them is changed rarely. I want to cache whole region (for each user), but i can not find the solution. Watching into the sourses gives no result too. Is anybody who knows is it possible, and how to do that? Thank you for every answer!

Comment: No you can't. Cache the blocks in the region in the Block UI

Comment: I'm guessing you actually mean in the performance admin screen (/admin/config/development/performance) rather than in the block UI screen

Comment: @LeighMason Yes. Was thinking of the way blocks can be cached in code (per user/page etc). This module [Block Cache Alter](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter) allows configuration for that apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather cache the individual blocks. There is a module for that: [Block Cache Alter](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockcache_alter)

> Alter cache settings per block. Cache settings per block are now set
>   in code, but if you don't like the default - usually none - you can
>   now easily change this. Install this to speed up block rendering for
>   authenticated users.

It will give you the optioon in the Block UI to alter the cache settings for that block:

[image]